# Best way to get only digits 0-9 and + from the variable

Tags: php

How to get only digits 0-9 and + from the following variable

```
$phone = “No +93-332-1121545”;
```

There may be some spaces and other characters in the variable that I don’t need.

I only need

```
$cleanPhone = “+933321121545”;
```

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^0-9+]/", "", 'No +93-332-1121545')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` to remove any characters other than the ones you want.

```
$cleanPhone = preg_replace('/[^\d+]/', '', $phone);
```